# How can I fix "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing" on a large project?

Tags: java, hibernate

I downloaded and installed the source code for the Perseus Project ([Open Source Code](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/opensource/download)) on to Ubuntu 14.04, and Tomcat 6. The project hasn't been modified in years, so it must be some new feature in hibernate that is doing this.

I see the solutions here on very many threads, but they address the issue of debugging code as it is being written as opposed to migrating a project that quite certainly worked "at one time". The code that I am working with hasn't been modified since 2008-2011. (I've determined that they are running it now on "Mandriva Linux 2010.2") Therefore, I need to be able to fix this issue on a large scale - either a search/replace method or a configuration file change. I have never used hibernate myself, so I don't understand the full meaning of the posted answers.

Thanks.

Also, the files don't use the @ annotated syntax, but the mappings seem to be done via XML files. At this point, I would not mind just to update all these files if I knew what to change.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="perseus.document.dao">
    <class name="HibernateChunkDAO$ChunkRow" table="hib_chunks" batch-size="10">

    <id name="id" type="int" column="id" unsaved-value="null">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="documentID" column="document_id" type="string"
        length="50" index="doc_idx doc_type_idx doc_type_value_idx
        doc_cid_idx doc_so_eo_idx doc_so_eo_type_idx doc_dq_idx
        doc_so_eo_type_val_idx" />

    <property name="elementName" column="element" type="string"
        length="20" />
    <property name="type" column="type" type="string" length="30"
        index="doc_type_idx doc_type_value_idx doc_so_eo_type_idx
        doc_so_eo_type_val_idx" />
    <property name="value" column="value" type="string" length="250"
        index="doc_type_value_idx doc_so_eo_type_val_idx" />

    <property name="position" column="position" type="int" />
    <property name="absolutePosition" column="abs_position" type="int" />

    <property name="chunkID" column="chunk_id" type="string"
        length="255" index="doc_cid_idx" />

    <property name="openTags" column="open_tags" type="text" />
    <property name="closeTags" column="close_tags" type="text" />

    <property name="startOffset" column="start_offset" type="int"
        index="doc_so_eo_idx doc_so_eo_type_idx doc_so_eo_type_val_idx" />
    <property name="endOffset" column="end_offset" type="int"
        index="doc_so_eo_idx doc_so_eo_type_idx doc_so_eo_type_val_idx" />

    <property name="displayQuery" column="display_query" type="string"
        length="100" index="doc_dq_idx" />
    <property name="head" column="head" type="text" />
    <property name="headLanguage" column="head_lang" type="string"
        length="10" />
    <property name="hasCustomHead" column="custom_head" type="boolean" />

        <set name="frequencies" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan"
            lazy="true" batch-size="30">
            <key column="chunk_id" on-delete="cascade" />
            <one-to-many class="perseus.ie.freq.Frequency" />
        </set>

        <many-to-one name="lemma" column="lemma_id" cascade="all" lazy="false" />

        <!--
        <list name="senses" inverse="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan"
            lazy="false" batch-size="30">
            <key column="chunk_id" />
            <list-index column="position" />
            <one-to-many class="perseus.voting.Sense" />
        </list>
-->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to below reason:

**You have defined a association in your entity which is not yet persisted in the database and before persisting this association you are trying to flush the Session.For example you have a  collection association which has collection of transient instances, so you have to  persist this collection first before flushing.**

For resolving this issue, you have 2 options:

1. Either manually persist the collection in your code by calling Session.save() method.
2. If you want to use tags in Hibernate XML file or want to use annotations make use of cascade="all" (for xml) or cascade=CascadeType.ALL (for  annotations) on your collection association.

Comment: I've updated the XML definition file above. Can you point to where I should add cascade=CascadeType.ALL?